# Get the four corners of a rectangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, transformation

[image: Illustration of the problem]

I have a boundary given ($xMin$, $yMin$, $xMax$, $yMax$) and the two points of a reference line of a rectangle. The begin point is at $(x_b, y_b)$ and the end point is at $(x_e, y_e)$. This reference line tells the rectangle's angle and length.

If we transform the reference line so that it is parallel to the x-axis and its begin point is on the left of the end point, the outer side is above the inner side.

[image: Illustration of the transformed sample]

I need to get the four corners of the rectangle. The parallel sides is then categorized as outer side or inner side. So the four sides is represented by:

- begin point of outer side: $(x_{ob}, y_{ob})$
- begin point of inner side: $(x_{ib}, y_{ib})$
- end point of outer side: $(x_{oe}, y_{oe})$
- end point of inner side: $(x_{ie}, y_{ie})$

The width can now be computed as distance between the two begin or end points.

The perpendicular sides' slope is negative reciprocal of the reference line's slope: $$m=-\frac{x_e-x_b}{y_e-y_b}$$

The begin side has equation of (eq1): $$y=-\frac{x_e-x_b}{y_e-y_b}(x-x_b)+y_b$$
which is the same for the end side (eq2): $$y=-\frac{x_e-x_b}{y_e-y_b}(x-x_e)+y_e$$

After this, I am lost to what to do next. I know that I need to use the boundary values to substitute from eq1 and eq2.

Comment: do you need the coordinates in the original reference frame or in the rotated one?

Comment: The original one

Comment: Then you don't need to rotate the frame, just find the two normals to your reference line, passing from its extremes, and force the adequate values of $x_{Min}$, $x_{Max}$, $y_{Min}$, $y_{Max}$ to find, respectively, $y_{ib}$, $y_{oe}$, $x_{ie}$, $x_{ob}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the reference line isn’t parallel to any edge (in which case the bounding rectangle *is* the rectangle). Consider the case $x_b<x_e$, $y_b<y_e$. Let $\Delta x=x_e-x_b$ and $\Delta y=y_e-y_b$. Then, from inspection of the corresponding picture, the four corners of the rectangle can be seen to be $$\begin{align}
ib &= (x_{max}-\Delta x, y_{min}) \\
ie &= (x_{max},y_{min}+\Delta y) \\
ob &= (x_{min},y_{max}-\Delta y) \\
oe &= (x_{min}+\Delta x,y_{max}).
\end{align}$$ (Note that these formulas also work for $\Delta x>0$, $\Delta y=0$.)

The other three cases can either be handled separately in a similar manner, or by permuting the given values (i.e., by rotating through a suitable multiple of $\frac\pi2$), applying the above formula, and finally reversing the permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets define

- begin point of outer side: $B_o = (x_{ob}, y_{ob})$
- begin point of inner side: $B_i = (x_{ib}, y_{ib})$
- end point of outer side: $E_o = (x_{oe}, y_{oe})$
- end point of inner side: $E_i = (x_{ie}, y_{ie})$

The slopes of the segments $\overline{B_oE_o}$ and $\overline{B_iE_i}$ have to be equal

$$m = \dfrac{y_{oe} - y_{ob}}{x_{oe} - x_{ob}}
    = \dfrac{y_{ie} - y_{ib}}{x_{ie} - x_{oib}}$$

Both of these segments are parallel to the line $y=mx$.

Assuming that $m$ is a negative number, we want to rotate the points through the angle $\theta$ where

$$\cos \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}} \qquad
  \sin \theta = \dfrac{-m}{\sqrt{1 + m^2}}$$

So the rotations can be represented by

$\begin{pmatrix}
    \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
    \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y
\end{pmatrix}
= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & m \\
    -m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y
\end{pmatrix}
$

So

$B_o \mapsto 
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & m \\
    -m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{ob} \\
    y_{ob}
\end{pmatrix}$

$B_i \mapsto 
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & m \\
    -m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{ib} \\
    y_{ib}
\end{pmatrix}$

$E_o \mapsto 
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & m \\
    -m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{oe} \\
    y_{oe}
\end{pmatrix}$

$E_i \mapsto 
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & m \\
    -m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{ie} \\
    y_{ie}
\end{pmatrix}$

In the image shown below, $m = -\dfrac 34$ The rotation matrix turned out to be
$\begin{pmatrix}
    0.8 & -0.6 \\
    0.6 & 0.8
\end{pmatrix}$

[image]